# SSRS 2016 - cannot see parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am self-learning SSRS via Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, VS 2015. I am using tutorial from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBYn1DU3VMQ&index=5&list=PL7A29088C98E92D5F)

I cannot see the parameter I created in preview. The visible has been selected in parameter properties. What have I missed out? Thanks in advance if anyone can help me.

. Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, VS 2015

. Microsoft SQL Server management studio 2016

Design
 [image]

Preview
[image]

Parameter Properties
  [image]

Comment: Had the same thing happen to me yesterday! Closed and reopened VS, then all started working properly. Strange!

Comment: @R.Richards - OMG. Very strange - it works. Are we suppose to do this everytime? Is there problem between Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools VS 2015 and Microsoft SQL Server management studio 2016?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I think the SSDT are mildly unstable. Yesterday was the first time I saw this. If I see if more, I may submit a bug report on it, if I can reproduce it consistently.

Comment: Same problem happened with me . While i closed rdl file and reopen and then previewed . it's solved . Try that .

Answer (score 29):

SSDT/Visual studio is strange and strange glitches such as this occur quite often. Another similar glitch is when changing the dataset sql query, sometimes you will have to delete reportname.rdl.data in the project folder for the changes to occur.

Saving and reopening is the only guaranteed way to fix your problem.

Answer (score 22):

I have seen the same issue. You don't even need to close and reload the project or VS 2015 (SSDT), you can simply close and reopen the report and then the parameters should display fine. I haven't been able to always reproduce this, maybe it is when a parameter is added because I just had this happen to me again. Definitely a bug that needs to be filed.

Comment: I did create a connect item for this, but unfortunately not able to current reproduce or determine steps that cause this. I am unable to currently attach files to the connect item either currently and I have contact connect support as well to include the screenshots.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3112758

Comment: I had this problem after linking to a second report. I will try these suggestions and add to this.

Answer (score 5):

Save and close VS. Reopen the project OR Unload and Re-load your Reports Project.

The parameters will now appear!

It worked for me.Visual Studio 2015 my version worked

Answer (score 4):

Save and close VS. Reopen the project  OR Unload and Re-load your Reports Project.

The parameters will now appear!

I had this same problem. Super frustrating.

Comment: I had the exact the same issue, after closed SSDT and reload the project, it indeed reappears.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the solution is to save all the work and close the program and then open again. It will start to appear.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to consistently cause it by setting parameter visibility to internal. Changing back to Visible does not impress it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easily missed tiny little arrow in the top middle of the preview screen which hides or unhides parameters - try clicking on this. Same thing applies in report server by the way.

Comment: Thanks for replying back I I tried that (the arrow points upwards and downwards when you lick on it), several times before positing the question.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened a few times to me and I don't have a solution. (I can also confirm that it relates to hiding a parameter.)

However I did find I was able to tab to the parameter field(s) and fill them in, then press enter to view the report, which is useful when in the middle of a project and restarting is more frustrating than tabbing to fill in a parameter or two.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue in the Report Server, where the parameters were hidden when the report was drilled to via some URL by adding "Parameters=false to the actual hyperlink.  It turns out I had the parameters disabled right in the URL.  Might be obvious to some, but it took me some time to figure out.  Sharing in case this helps anyone else.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if the window is not large enough to display all parameter values, then no parameters are displayed after the initial preview. Drag the window bar down to expose all parameters while in preview mode.  When dragging, don't click on the 'up' arrow, but click on the bar.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using SQL Server 2016 Report Builder? You should be able to perform most operations that you see in that tutorial in this tool. This tool allows you to create, design and publish reports and shared data sets to SQL Server Reporting Services 2016 and 2017. You can download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53613).