# Using Parameters in Visual Studio 2015 Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to get a parameter drop-down onto my report in Visual Studio 2015. It shows up fine on the design view, here i have populated it from another data set containing a unique list of one of the columns:

[image]

But when i go to the Preview tab, the parameters area is empty..

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is not your parameter set to internal or be hidden?

Comment: If this isn't the hidden or internal setting, then close and reopen VS. I had a similar issue and that seemed to fix it. Not sure why it happened, haven't really seen it since.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta no, i have checked that and it's set to visible. I'll try restarting VS now.

Comment: @R.Richards damn that sorted it - ill accept that as an answer.

Comment: having same problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the first question about this issue. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291811/ssrs-2016-cannot-see-parameter) is another one. I cannot say why this happens, and I have not been able to reproduce it either. As I mentioned in the other question, if I see it again I may submit a bug report on it, if I can reproduce it consistently.

The solution/fix to the issue was to close Visual Studio and restart it. Afterward, the parameters worked as expected. I am sure we can all agree this isn't ideal, but it is a work around.

More to come if I find anything!

Comment: same issue here please find something

Comment: i also have this report viewer issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599611/ssrs-report-files-rdl-how-to-upgrade-to-latest

not sure if you can answer this thread